# Can not launch bcftools using python's subprocess module, as it only accepts first command of commands list

Tags: python, bcftools

I am trying to remove samples from a chromosome vcf file. I wrote a function that takes chromosome number and a list of samples to remove. When I try to run bcftools using subprocess module it only runs bcftools, as if I was running `subprocess.run([bcftools], shell=True, env=my_env)` instead of:

```py
subprocess.run(['bcftools', 'view', in_vcf, '--samples', drop_samples, '-Oz', '>', out_vcf], shell=True, env=my_env)
```

The function:

```py
def remove_individuals(chr_samples):
    my_env = os.environ.copy()
    my_env['PATH'] = f'/home/aydar/bin/bcftools_1.11/bin/:{my_env["PATH"]}'
    def remove_indiv(chr, indiv):
        in_vcf = f'data.filtered-updated-{chr}.vcf.gz'
        out_vcf = f'data.filtered-updated-{chr}-faulty-samp-rem.vcf.gz'
        drop_samples = "\'^"+",".join(indiv)+"\'"
        proc = subprocess.run(
            ['bcftools', 'view', in_vcf, 
             '--samples', drop_samples, '-Oz', '>', out_vcf],
            shell=True,
            env=my_env
        )
        print(proc.args)
    chr_samples.apply(lambda x: remove_indiv(x.index[0], list(x.values[0])))
```

function input:

```
13,[2500000075_2500000075,2000000171_2000000171,1800000179_1800000179,330134048_330134048]
```

When I run the same command in the terminal everything works.

The command I test with in terminal:

```
bcftools view data.filtered-updated-13.vcf.gz --samples '^2500000075_2500000075,2000000171_2000000171,1800000179_1800000179,330134048_330134048' -Oz > out_test_vcf.gz
```

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer. Using `popen` is the standard approach here than using `run`. Anyway could you very kindly mark your answer as "accepted"? This help site stats and prevents the question from being re-introduced as unresolved later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. As it turned out I had to write to file like so and extra quotes `("\'")` around samples were not needed. Also shell=True does not work well with lists, only strings:

```py
def remove_individuals(chr_samples):
    my_env = os.environ.copy()
    my_env['PATH'] = f'/home/aydar/bin/bcftools_1.11/bin/:{my_env["PATH"]}'
    def remove_indiv(chr, indiv):
        in_vcf = f'data.filtered-updated-{chr}.vcf.gz'
        out_vcf = f'data.filtered-updated-{chr}-faulty-samp-rem.vcf.gz'
        drop_samples = "^"+",".join(indiv)
        out = subprocess.run(
            ['bcftools', 'view', in_vcf, 
             '--samples', drop_samples, '-Oz'],
            env=my_env,
            capture_output=True
        )
        with open(out_vcf, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(out.stdout)
    chr_samples.apply(lambda x: remove_indiv(x.index[0], list(x.values[0])))
```

Remember to use `'wb'` if you like me and use `Oz` output option, because it returns bgzipped file.

Comment: thanks for accepting your answer and please feel free to ask a question any time here.